# Unable to get password for the instance created from AMI

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

The following code successfully creates an instance.

```
try {
        $ec2 = new Ec2Client($options);
        $result = $ec2->runInstances([
             'ImageId' => 'ami-xxxxxxxx', // REQUIRED
             'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior' => 'stop',
             'InstanceType' => 't1.micro',
             'MaxCount' => 1, // REQUIRED
             'MinCount' => 1, // REQUIRED,
             'EbsOptimized' => false, // SEE COMMENT
             'KeyName' => 'TestCloud',
             'Monitoring' => [
                'Enabled' => true // REQUIRED
              ]
        ]);
    }catch(Exception $exc) {
        var_dump($exc);
    }
```

But when I try to retrieve the password to connect (RDP) to that instance from the `aws console`, I get the following error:

```
Password is not available.
This instance was launched from a custom AMI, or the default password has changed. 
A password cannot be retrieved for this instance. If you have forgotten your password, 
you can reset it using the Amazon EC2 configuration service. For
more information, see Passwords for a Windows Server Instance.
```

Earlier I created the `AMI` directly from a running `EC2` instance.

What could be the reason for this? What is the thing being missed?

Comment: How was `ami-xxxxxxxx` created? Is it an AWS-supplied AMI?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I created the AMI directly from a running EC2 instance.

Comment: How was that "running EC2 instance" launched? Was it from an AWS-supplied AMI? Can you successfully use the "Get Windows Password" function on that original instance?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, "Get Windows Password" function works fine on the former instance. It was launched from AWS launch wizard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Get Windows Password` facility should only be used for **initial access to a Windows EC2 instance**.

A random password is generated for the Administrator account. The password is then encrypted with the public half of the Key Pair used to launch the instance. The encrypted password is then supplied back to EC2 via the **System Log**. (You can often see it by using the **Get System Log** command in the management console.)

To access the server, the password needs to be decrypted with the private half of the Key Pair. This can be done in the console via the **Get Windows Password** action.

**Very important:** Once you have accessed the server, **change the password!** Or, better yet, add the instance to an Active Directory domain. The encrypted password is intended to provide *initial* access to an instance. It should not be used as an on-going security mechanism.

Given the error message you have received, it appears that the instance is **not sending the encrypted password via the System Log**. Therefore, EC2 is unable to decrypt it. This could be because the AMI was not created from an AWS-supplied image (which uses `EC2Config` to create the encrypted password and report it via the System Log), or the configuration on the instance has changed in some way not to run that utility.

Comment: AMI was created from an already running EC2 instance, which was created from the Launch Instance wizard on the amazon console. This machine easily creates a password on `Get Password`. But now the new machine created is failing to generate password. What is the correct way to launch an instance?

Comment: No idea. It should be working given the situation you describe.

Comment: I am facing the same issue and the Massage is similar,

when we hit get password
it shows the similar message

and I detach the Volume and attached the same to other Machine but the EC2Config in 
C:\programs\Amazon\?

So its very hard to reset the Password for, even the AWS document is Failed to get it done.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I would like to know that why we should change the password once accessed the server through keypair. Is there any strong security reason? Please clarify me.

Comment: Why would you change the password straight away? In the case of a linux instance then that key is the key to SSH onto the machine, so if that's not secure then neither is the linux equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

```
This instance was launched from a custom AMI!
```

Please read throughly when you use **CUSTOM AMI** : 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/troubleshooting-windows-instances.html

> The accounts and passwords provided are based on the AMI that you used to launch the instance. You can either retrieve the auto-generated password for the Administrator account, or **use the account and password that were in use in the original instance from which the AMI was created**.

You DON'T need to generate a new password, nor AWS will allow it. You just connect to the new instances using the SAME RDP password set on the previous instance the generate the current AMI.

This is the CORRECT behavior.  Imagine you customise your whole AWS EC2 , you don't want anyone easily overwrite the RDP access to the EC2 instances.

This also mean, after you customise your instances and you mess up the password, you just cannot create a snapshot from it and hope AWS will reset the password inside the server.

Comment: But I am unable to connect either.

Comment: In your reply to JohnRotenstein, you say, ' **Yes, "Get Windows Password" function works fine on the former instance. It was launched from AWS launch wizard.  ' **
Did you lost the original instance RDS password? The RDS password is the same if you customise an AMI out of that instance.  If you lost the password, this is not the way to "reset" the RDS password. If the original instance is launch from EBS, you may have a change to mount it from another EC2 to recover/reset the password, if it is not encrypted.

Comment: "using the SAME RDP password", this is gold. I spent hours trying to figure out why I got "Please wait at least 4 minutes after launching an instance before trying to retrieve the auto-generated password." until I saw your answer here....

Comment: @mootmoot I agreed with you point made. But if I forget or loss the old password, then how can I RDP to newly launched instance? Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

If you started the instance from a custom AMI (ie. A snapshot) this feature is not available anymore. You will need to reset the password.

If you have lost your Windows administrator password and are using a Windows AMI before Windows Server 2016, you can use the EC2Config service to generate a new password -> [Resetting windows Admin Pass with EC2Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html)

If you have lost your Windows administrator password and are using a Windows Server 2016 or later AMI, you can use the EC2Rescue tool, which uses the EC2Launch service to generate a new password -> [Resetting windows Admin Pass with EC2Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Launch.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you have created AMI from custom windows instance
then before creating Image:

- Get password using pem file
- save the password somewhere
- now create the image and use that password that you saved

you will not get password later after creating AMI from WIN instance.